# Does display:none prevent a video from being downloaded

Tags: css, video

I have a 22MB video on my homepage but when the screen goes narrow, the entire `div` won't show, to prevent it loading slowly on a phone.

Is the page still downloading the video and just not showing (bad thing) or is the CSS `display:none` preventing it from downloading (good thing).

Comment: Programming questions, such as this, are best asked on Stackoverflow. They are off topic here.

Comment: @Rob This isn't necessarily just programming related... it's directly relevant to a webmaster managing bandwidth on a site.

Comment: @w3dk The question is about what `display:none;` does which is a CSS question which is off topic here.

Comment: Videos are a bit more complex than something like an image, since the browser might only download a portion anyway, unless it is "played" in its entirety. Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading

Comment: `if (is_mobile == true) { //do something }` is your friend.

Comment: @SimonHayter Shouldn't the logic be the other way round... `if (is_mobile == false) { //load all the bandwidth heavy videos 'n' stuff }`?

Comment: @w3dk hehe, actually you can use either, true or false, since you could use `is_mobile == true` along with `is_desktop == true` then you can set serve different content within that area. You could also use `is_desktop == true { // Ever Drunk Baileys From a Shoe }` with `else { // of course I like socks, I wear socks }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still being downloaded, and hidden, if you use display:none.

Comment: Have you actually tested it with something like Fiddler?

Comment: @wb9688 - I haven't. I pretty much like the layout the way it is but might be considering making sure the video is super low quality or something.

Comment: How can you avoid the video from being downloaded?